# Opengl Games: Do i have to know 3d related math to create good opengl games?

Tags: opengl, shader

I read about OpenGL and about nvidia-cg-toolkit and other shaders, all contains lots of math problems and math formulas for effects and such.

I want to be able to make proper 3d games that use the GPU as much as possible.

Do I have to use a 3d Engine if the math related info does not interest me ?
if so, can anyone recommend of a good one that uses GPU for all the shading and such ?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Graphics is all about linear algebra.

Comment: "uses GPU for all the shading and such" -> you have no choice but to use the GPU for all the shading and such

Comment: @Alexander: yes but also quaternions, fourier transform, spherical harmonics...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out Unity3D.  Create awesome games, great editor, easy to learn scripting and no maths required!  Create for iPhone, iPad, Playstation, Wii, 360, web and PC.

[Unity 3d website here](http://unity3d.com/)

Answer (score 3):

There are many parts in a game.

Without linear algebra background, you can do : scripting, networking, gameplay, sound, camera (partially), limited animation, full animation if the engine is complete enough, some rendering, visual assets, external tools, ...

You won't be able to do : the core of a 3d engine, shaders, many rendring tricks.

Sadly, the latter are the most interesting IMHO

Answer (score 2):

As you've mentioned, if you are not interested in all the math stuff, i recommend using a pre-built graphics engine.

i recommend "Allegro library", which according to Wikipedia has binding for Ada, C++, C#, D, Lisp, Lua, Mercury, Pascal, Perl, Python and Scheme.